# Saving part of found term when replacing in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I want to use Notepad++ to find/replace large chunks of code, but a hefty part of it deals with arrays. How can I put a "variable" in Notepad++'s Find/Replace window so that part of it can be saved and not overwritten?

The below example isn't perfect, as it could be converted using two simple find/replace searches, but I'd like to do something to the effect of `Find: o[*]` and `Replace: p*`.

**Example**

Original:

```
Or(a=o[0]);
Or(a=o[1]);
Or(a=o[2]);
Or(a=o[3]);
Or(a=o[4]);
```

What I need:

```
Or(a=p0);
Or(a=p1);
Or(a=p2);
Or(a=p3);
Or(a=p4);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you enable the Regular expression radio button, you can use parenthesis to hold values.

Whatever is contained within the first `()` gets stored in `\1`, the second in `\2` and so on.

Here's a basic illustration of that for your example.

[image: variable replacement in notepad++]
*The `\d` matches a digit.* `[` and `]` have to be escaped with `\` because they are special characters.

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I need. I haven't quite taken the jump to learn regex yet, but I'm getting there. :) Thank you!